# Using ScrollView but Button not shows bottom of page

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I want create a page with ScrollView. I want set Button in bottom of page and I want main root of xml should LinearLayout and inner LinearLayout I use ScrollView. I write this code, but button not shows bottom. when i add Button in another LinearLayout with bottom gravity, again the program not shows button in bottom of page. anyway, this is my code. If you can, please sort my code with minimum nested layout.

file.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/linear1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="#ffffff">
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/buttonSend"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/send_selector"/>
     <LinearLayout 
         android:id="@+id/linear2"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="vertical">   
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/oldPass"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/oldPass"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editOldPass"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:password="true"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/textbox"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/newPass"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/newPass"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editNewPass"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:password="true"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/textbox"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/duplicateNewPass"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/duplicateNewPass"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editDuplicatNewPass"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:password="true"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The important thing to notice is the added `View` with layout_weight set to "1". It uses all the empty space if it's shorter than the ScrollView. However it only does so when `android:fillViewport="true"` is set on the `ScrollView`.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/oldPass"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="oldPass"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"        
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editOldPass"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:password="true"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/newPass"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="newPass"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editNewPass"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:password="true"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/duplicateNewPass"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="duplicateNewPass"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editDuplicatNewPass"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:password="true"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        />

    <View 
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/buttonSend"
            />

    </LinearLayout>  

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/linear2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/oldPass"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/oldPass"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editOldPass"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:password="true"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/textbox"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/newPass"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/newPass"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editNewPass"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:password="true"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/textbox"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/duplicateNewPass"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/duplicateNewPass"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editDuplicatNewPass"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:password="true"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/buttonSend"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks but i want button in scrollView not out of scrollview.